# how to run mysql from the command line on mac?

Tags: mysql

I want to run MYSQL from the command line, as in

```
mysql -u root -p
```

but it returns

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

So, need to install it, I think. But then what application exactly do I need to install? I see a dozen applications here: `http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/`, installed some, but still can't use mysql from the command line.

I'm using mavericks. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd just go with a [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) box. Installing server software on your dev box is always a pain, especially on a mac

Comment: I'd second Phil's recommendation about Vagrant, but if you must have MySQL on your Mac, try here: http://machiine.com/2013/how-to-setup-mysql-on-a-mac-with-osx-10-8-mamp-part-2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MySQL does not separate the server and client downloads, so you basically just need to download the entire MySQL version -- while it will download the binaries for the server it won't actually start or set-up a server unless you explicitly intend to.

You can go to the download URL (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and select "Mac OS X" from platform and download "Mac OS X 10.7 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive"

The default MySQL installation installs to `/usr/local/mysql` which is not in your path, specifically the MySQL client is installed at `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

You can specify it exactly to launch the client:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

If you would like a GUI client I can highly recommend "Sequel Pro" or "MySQL Workbench"

Comment: Trent is right. It's worth mentioning as well that you could use MAMP.... if your needs are short term, just use that (or SQLite). If you need to run MySQL on your Mac (which frankly seems a bit unlikely) Trent's response is very good.

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you a workaround to achieve your wishes...

1. Create a script to run the specific path for you, lets call it `connect_to_my_sql.c`:

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  int
  main() {
    system("/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root");
  }
```

2. Compile your C script:

```
  gcc -o mysql connect_to_my_sql.c
```

3. Move your binary file (i.e. your mysql file) to a folder in your path:

```
  mv mysql /usr/local/bin
```

4. Now, you should be able to run MySQL by typing `mysql` everywhere from the terminal.

Alternatively, create an `Alias` like so:

1. Open your ~/.bash_profile

```
  vi ~/.bash_profile
```

2. Add following line to your bash_profile:

```
  alias mysql="/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root"
```

3. Source your bash_profile

```
  source ~/.bash_profile
```

4. Should be able to run MySQL by typing `mysql` everywhere from the terminal.